# Laravel How to setup a public_html folder in a shared hosting in hostinger

Tags: php, laravel, storage, hosting, shared-hosting

I'm trying to host a Laravel project in a shared hosting using Hostinger and I am having problems with the assets. The sample folder is here [sample folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbMhK.png), I'm not really sure on how to make this connection with my public folder and resources folder. I've already use `php artisan storage:link` before I uploaded the project.

Comment: Running locally before upload won't work since it uses the full path to the storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't have shell access in your shared hosting account.

One way to do this is to create a temporal route that runs the artisan command.

Firstly, before you upload, delete the existing storage link from public

`rm public/storage`

```
Route::get('create-symlink', function (){
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
    return response('Done...');
});
```

Remeber to remove or comment out the route when done.